# How to create a event log at "Application and Services Logs" section using c++

Tags: c++, event-viewer

I want to write logs in Event viewer under "Applications and Services logs"section using c++. But I cannot find any interface about it, Does anybody know?

I have tried "RegisterEventSource", "ReportEvent", but i can only write event viewer logs in Applications but not under Applications and Services logs.

I also find some samples in C#, but my application is in C++.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at the [`EventWrite`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/evntprov/nf-evntprov-eventwrite) function. It is contained in the `evntprov.h`. This allows you to write a specific entry to a Register Handle. By using [`EventRegister`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/evntprov/nf-evntprov-eventregister) you can create a Register Handle. Remember to call `EventUnregsiter` when you are done with the Register Handle.

I have unfortunately not worked with this in quite a while. Have a read over at [Windows Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/evntprov/) about `evntprov.h` and all its functionality. I am sure it will point you in the correct direction.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do you know where to find the log written by EventWrite, I cannot find them at Event Viewer. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. I can't remember the exact working of these functions. As far as I remember it depends on the Event Register. But give the Windows Doc a read.

Comment: You can launch a tracing session with an ETW consumer like XPerf.exe, configuring it to capture your specific guid.